# Writing $f(x,y)$ as $\Phi(g(x) + h(y))$

Tags: real-analysis

Could you prove or disprove the following statement?

> Let 
>   $f\colon[0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ 
>   be a continuous function.  Then
>   there are continuous functions 
>   $g,\ h\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and
>   $\Phi\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$
>   such that  $$ f(x,y) = \Phi(g(x) + h(y)).$$

(This problem popped up in my mind while I was thinking about [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47557/) related one on MO.  I couldn't find an easy proof or a disproof. This version is much weaker than the one asked at MO, since $g$ and $h$ do depend on $f$ here.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is not true.

To make the counterexample simpler, I will take $f:[-1,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Let *f(x,y)=xy*.  So we have

```
---0+++
---0+++
0000000
+++0---
+++0---
```

Consider the image of *xy=0* in *g(x)+h(y)*.  Since it's a connected, compact set, the image is connected and compact, so an interval [m,n], with $\Phi([m,n])=0$.  We may assume that $\Phi(n+\epsilon)>0$ and $\Phi(m-\epsilon)<0$.  Let *A=g(1)*, *a=g(-1)*, *B=h(1)*, *b=h(-1)*.

Then we have $A+B>n, \; a+b>n, \;  A+b<m, \; a+B<m$, which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused here. Are you sure you want $\Phi(m + \epsilon) > 0$ and $\Phi(n - \epsilon) < 0$? Don't you mean $\Phi(m - \epsilon) > 0$ and $\Phi(n + \epsilon) < 0$ or another variant? Probably I'm just being stupid and missing something...

Comment: @Adrian: No, you're completely right!  Thanks for the correction; I was too hasty and mixed up m and n.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is such that $f(x,0)$ and $f(0,y)$ are monotonic in $x$ and $y$ respectively over $[0,1]$. Since $f(x,0) = \Phi(g(x) + h(0))$, it must be the case that $g$ is monotonic over $[0,1]$. Similarly, $h$ is monotonic over $[0,1]$. So $g(x) + h(y)$ is the sum of monotonic functions. It's not hard to show that for any $(x,y)$ in the interior of $[0,1]^2$, there must be a point on the boundary with the same value of $g(x) + h(y)$, and therefore the same value of $\Phi(g(x) + h(y))$. Since it's easy to construct a continuous $f$ which satisfies the first assumption yet takes a larger range of values in the interior than it does on the boundary (for any $f$ that doesn't, try adding $M x(1-x)y(1-y)$ for large enough $M$), this contradicts the conjecture.

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = x+y$. It satisfies your assumptions, but doesn't lead to a counterexample.

Comment: @AgCl: You're right, I shouldn't have said "Choose *any* $f$". I'll edit.